# Entire function such that $f(z) = a f(z+1)= b f(z+i)$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f(z)$ be a non-zero entire function such that $\forall z, \ f(z) = a f(z+1)= b f(z+i)$

If $a = e^w, b = e^{iw}$ then $f(z) = C e^{-wz}$. Why is there no solution if there is no such $w$ ?

Comment: Seems related to modular forms on the elliptic curve $\mathbb{C} / (\mathbb{Z} + i \mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: The analog on $\mathcal{H}/SL_2(\Bbb{Z})$ would be $f$ holomorphic on $\Im(z) > 0$ and $f(z) = a f(z+1) = b f(-1/z)$, does it have a solution ? For $a=b=1$ then $j(z)$ is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

If $a=e^w$ and $g(z)=e^{wz}f(z)$, then $g(z)=g(z+1)=be^{-iw}g(z+i)$.

Now $g(z)=h(e^{2i\pi z})$ for some $h$ analytic in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, and $h(z)=be^{-iw}h(e^{-2\pi}z)$ for all $z\neq 0$. Comparing Laurent expansions, we have $1=be^{-iw-2n\pi}$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. But then $$a=e^{w-2in\pi},\qquad b=e^{i(w-2in\pi)}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $a = e^w$, then $g(z)=f(z) e^{wz} = g(z+1) = \frac{b}{a} g(z+i)$.

$g(z) = \sum_n d_n e^{2i \pi n z}$,

$g(z+1) = \frac{b}{a} g(z+i)$ implies $|g(z)| = O( |b/a|^{1+|\Im(z)|})$ so that $g(z) = \sum_{n=-N}^N  d_n e^{2i \pi n z}$ where $N = \lfloor \frac{\log |b/a|}{2\pi} \rfloor$ from there the result should be clear